# Center left margin but right margin 100% of viewport (to the end)

Tags: html, css, width

I have been facing an issue which I am finding difficulty to resolve.

Basically, I would like a div to start at the left position of margin 0 auto and finish on the edge of the viewport. Please see the diagram below to help illustrate this.

A basic bit of the HTML is this...

```
<div style="max-width:500px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div> <!-- needs to start at left margin and stretch to 100% of viewport -->
    <ul>
     <li></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: image of problem]

Any help would be appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's quite achievable. Before using `calc`, however, keep in mind that it is CSS 3 and comes with [some usability limitations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) (no IE8, no Opera Mini).

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container > div {
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.container > div > ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container > div > ul > li {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.container > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  width: calc(((100vw - 100%) / 2) + 100%);
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <!-- needs to start at left margin and stretch to 100% of viewport -->
    <ul>
      <li>first li</li>
      <li>second li</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Most of the CSS is to make it look like your picture. But the model is:

```
.grand-parent {
    width: {some-fixed-width}; // 500px in our case
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.child {
    width: calc(((100vw - 100%) / 2) + 100%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Some of them are not even present in my above code, as they are defaults, but they are important for this to work. If you decide to use some padding on the parent you have to compensate for it in child, both in calc (`100%` becomes `100%` + `left-padding of parent` + `right-padding-of-parent`) and in left margin (`negative left margin of parent`). But, to keep it simple, don't use left and right margins or paddings on parent. :))

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gwakfrdw/).

Comment: This is perfect! width: calc(((100vw - 100%) / 2) + 100%);  is the key line! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

See example : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmk7bxp8/)

HTML:

```
<div class="abc">
  <div class="new">
    <ul>
      <li>123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.abc{width:500px; margin: 0 auto; background:#ccc; overflow:hidden; height:500px;}
.new{width:100%; background:#ff0000;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

```
<div class="container" style="position: relative; border: 1px solid orange; min-height:200px;">
<div style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="border: 1px solid blue;position: absolute;right: 0;width: calc(100% - 300px);"> <!-- needs to start at left margin and stretch to 100% of viewport -->
  test data
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

but still it is not achievable. You would have to use javascript to calculate the width of the div which needs to be placed with the viewport right position. Applying position absolute and right 0 would shift it to the right. just that the width calculation needs to be handled.